# How can I use my Minolta 3500xi flash with my Sony A camera?

Tags: flash, sony, minolta

My external flash, a Minolta 3500xi, doesn't seem to be synchronized with my camera Sony A 200. Can you help?

Comment: I've provided a quick answer, but it might help if you can explain more what you're trying to do, what you expect, and what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this flash is compatible with your camera in auto mode — [forum posts seem to confirm this](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/37644246), and [this blog post](http://alphasight.blogspot.com/2008/10/minolta-program-3500xi-flash.html) goes into greater detail. In short, you can use it as a manual flash, either at full power or at ¼ power (with the "Lo" button), but can't get further automation (or wireless optical control).

The flash has a guide number of 35 meters when zoomed all the way in to its 105mm setting — this corresponds to a lens of about 70mm on your α200, since those numbers are given for a 35mm film camera frame. At the 50mm zoom setting, it's GN 29m, and at the widest 28mm setting it's GN 22m (again, that's a decently-wide ~18mm on your camera, so the flash's zoom range pairs nicely with the 18-70mm kit lens). The Lo button will halve the effective GN, which gives you a bit of flexibility.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry I can't upvote (this account is a throw-away). The 3500xi was a low-end flash that depended on TTL/OTF (philosophically not far from the current low-end Nikon and Canon units). To get real manual power settings (full stops down to 1/16, IIRC) or "Auto thyristor" mode at the same Minolta vintage, you had to get the 5400xi. It's still OTF, so no digital TTL, but manual and Auto still make it useful.